# $\left[\csc^2\frac{\alpha}{2}+\csc^2\frac{\beta}{2}+\csc^2\frac{\gamma}{2}\right]=2$

Tags: trigonometry, ceiling-and-floor-functions

If $\cos \alpha \cos \beta \cos \gamma-\cos \alpha-\cos \beta-\cos \gamma+1=0$
 and $\alpha\neq\beta\neq\gamma\neq2n\pi$,then prove that $\left[\csc^2\frac{\alpha}{2}+\csc^2\frac{\beta}{2}+\csc^2\frac{\gamma}{2}\right]=2$

---

$\cos \alpha \cos \beta \cos \gamma+1=\cos \alpha+\cos \beta+\cos \gamma$
$\cos \alpha \cos \beta \cos \gamma+1=2\cos^2 \frac{\alpha}{2}+2\cos^2 \frac{\beta}{2}+2\cos^2 \frac{\gamma}{2}-3$

But there seems no method to calculate the value of the required expression.Some hints and suggestions are needed.

Comment: what does this mean $[...]$?

Comment: is this the floor function?

Comment: yes this is floor function.@Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: Sir @G-man,i am sure about the value 2(it is given in the book),but i am not sure of the square bracket whether it is floor function or not.It is not written in the book that it is a floor function.

Comment: Sir expression is correct.No mistake.

Comment: @G-man there is a condition which is involved in this problem. It's written in the first line of the question.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

As $\csc^2\dfrac x2=\dfrac2{1-\cos x},$

Please simplify 
$$\dfrac2{1-\cos\alpha}+\dfrac2{1-\cos\beta}+\dfrac2{1-\cos\gamma}=2$$ to reach at the given condition